# Is there a way to specify what to do when a class is first used?

Tags: vb.net

I am inspired by

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/277669-using-new-in-module/

The idea is that the new in module is called once and only once when anything in the module is used.

Module is like a static class they said.

Now what about regular class. Can we have a function like that new in module? Called once when a class is used.

I know in class we have new that is called when an object of type class is used. What about a function called not every time an object of type class is made, but once and only once, when anything from that class is made. Sort of like new in module.

Is there such thing?

Comment: Declare a constructor with the `Shared` keyword.  Just like other `Shared` members, it will belong to the class rather than any particular instance of that class.

Comment: what is the effect of duplicate questions? Will my questions disappear because it's been duplicated? If anything it's search engine candy that make it easy for people to find the right question

Comment: will it be deleted? kindo f shame

Comment: @JimThio have a look at [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272111/what-happens-to-questions-closed-as-duplicate-in-the-long-term) meta question. To be honest it would make a good pointer in this case as it's not a question that frequently comes up.